# Splitting string into x substrings

Tags: java, string

I have a file containing 6 lines of text, I scan each line and assign it to a string (containing either 3-4 substrings), there are 3 variables to be assigned using the string. If the string contains 4 substrings then the 2nd and 3rd substring must be concatenated into the same string.

I originally split the string into an array but could not get it to work. I'm not asking for how to do it. Just in what direction I should go to solve the problem.

Please help

Comment: Just google the solution ...

Comment: So, "I'm not asking for how to do it. Just in what direction I should go to solve the problem." What answer are you expecting that will satisfy that statement? How about your first thing should be write some code?

Comment: is there a delimiter between the substrings?

Comment: assuming your substtings are commata(a delimiter) separated you can use .splt(",") to get the substrings

Comment: Arrays have a `length` property that would be helpful.

Comment: 1. Let `a`, `b` and `c` be the 3 variables you want to end up with. 2. split the line. 3. count the chunks. 4. assign first chunk to `a`. 5. if count is 3 assign second chunk to `b` and second chunk to `c`. 6. if count is 4 assign second and third chunk to `b` and fourth chunk to `c`. 7. deal with the alternate paths (line has too few or too much chunks, no line at all, etc...)

Comment: post your code ( [MCVE] ). It will be much easier to understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

Build a POJO which holds the three result Strings. Build methods which build the POJO from 3 or 4 Strings. 
Build another method which splits the original String into its substrings and call the other methods depending on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String[] split(String regex, int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) utility.

```
String s = "a b c d e f";
String[] list = s.split(" ", 3);
for (String x : list){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

You can see that the split function return an array of size 3 (or array of size `limit`). So by defining the limit as 3 you can get an array size of 3 and use them in variables. It tries to split the string on the given regex at most limit-1 times, as mentioned in the docs.
[Sample Code](http://ideone.com/1pXprj)